gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: An exception was thrown while starting a component. Setting runlevel to SHUTDOWN
We have been trying to start the ClaimCenter server from TomCat. The server is getting started even though it throws exception with the message "ClaimCenter unable to start" in the logs.
Please find the log details below:
gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: An exception was thrown while starting a component. Setting runlevel to SHUTDOWN

Try to run billing center.

Add more of the stack trace leading up to and following this error and someone may be able to help you.
